# Nginx display just the Welcome page

Tags: nginx

I just set the nginx for a subdomain and even so I still get just the Welcome page.

Here is the code I set on nginx sites-available

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name sub.domain.ro;

    rewrite ^ https://sub.domain.ro$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    # ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/testsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/testsite.com/privkey.pem;
    # ssl_stapling on;

    server_name sub.domain.ro;

    root /var/www/sub.domain.ro;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Please let me know what I did wrong or what I forget here.

Comment: Test your configuration using `nginx -t`

Comment: it says 
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: If you use `nginx -T` with an uppercase `T` - can you see your `server` blocks?

Comment: Hm... Yes, I am, but just for the root domain, not for the subdomain too. why is it happen? The file is called sub.domain.com in /etc/nginx/sites-available

Comment: You need to start at the Nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and see what other files and directories are included using `include` statements. Also, if your platform includes files from `sites-enabled` - you may need to add a symbolic link from the `sites-available` directory.

Comment: on nginx.conf file I have this line "include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;"

Comment: I added the same file (sub.domain.ro) from sites-available to sites-enabled and the root domain stop working while the subdomain still display the same welcome message

Comment: Well done I was able to setup it, but when access the address it download a file instead, trying to install there Wordpress I added index.php on the list, If I remove it I get a 503 error